# how can i get the image property that is in .kv file and change the size in .py file

Tags: kivy

my python code is:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.theming import ThemeManager
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
login=Builder.load_file('login.kv')

class Login(BoxLayout):
    imge=ObjectProperty()
    def press(self):
        self.imge.size_hint=(.2,.2)

class Main(App): 
    def build(self):
        theme_cls=ThemeManager()
        return Login()
if __name__=="__main__":
    Main().run()
```

my .kv file is:

```
<Login>:
imge:img
Image:
    id:img
    source:'22.png' 
Button:
    text:"click"
    on_press:root.press()
```

i need to change the image size on click button,but the Objectproperty is not providing the image properties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So first of all you it is better using a boylayout when you want to use size_hints But it is your wish. In your case you have to give your image also size_hints

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.theming import ThemeManager
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
login=Builder.load_file('login.kv')


class Login(BoxLayout):
    image = ObjectProperty()

    def press(self):
        self.image.size_hint = (.2,.5)


class Main(App):
    def build(self):
        return Login()


if __name__=="__main__":
    Main().run()

kv file:
<Login>:
    image:img
    Image:
        size_hint:.5,1
        id:img
        source:'play.png'
    Button:
        text:"click"
        size_hint:.2,.1
        on_release:
            root.press()
```

With FloatLayout. When using boxlayout the button will also increase the size. So floatlayout is better

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.theming import ThemeManager
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
login=Builder.load_file('login.kv')


class Login(FloatLayout):
    image = ObjectProperty()

    def press(self):
        self.image.size_hint = (.2,.5)


class Main(App):
    def build(self):
        return Login()


if __name__=="__main__":
    Main().run()

and kv file 
<Login>:
    image:img
    Image:
        size_hint:.5,1
        id:img
        source:'play.png'
    Button:
        text:"click"
        size_hint:.2,.1
        on_release:
            root.press()
```

So check the effect with box and floatlayouts. Ur problem was u did not give the image size_hints in kv file